# Selenium using Python: Permission Denied to Launch Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, permissions, permission-denied

I'm a Python beginner and trying to use selenium to automate a web browsing process. Unfortunately, my attempts are not as smooth as I'd like them to be; for whatever reason, the command line is returning an error saying "permission denied" when I run the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

print(type(browser))
```

I've tried to read previous posts on this topic- specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40208762/3856609) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40156702/3856609)- but each to no avail. Either the compiler returns "permission denied," or in the case of adding `firefox.exe` to the end of the path, "entity not found."

I appreciate any help you could give me. If you could explain any help like you would to an 8-year old, it'd be particularly helpful- I'm still a novice to this stuff.

Edited to add: if it helps provide any context, I'm using Windows 10 and running Python on Visual Studio Community. I've also thought about using the `sudo` command for permission, but I'm not exactly sure how I'd do that from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `Firefox.exe` instead of `firefox.exe` to your path.

I've also had this issue before and it has worked for me, though I'm not exactly sure why.

Comment: Finally- it worked! Thanks for the suggestion. I'm open to other responses though, especially to see why the uppercase letter made the difference.

Comment: @daOnlyBG The uppercase letter matters because thats not the of the executable. File names and paths are case sensitive.

Comment: @heinst I'm aware they're case sensitive, but when I right-click on the Firefox executable and inspect its properties, its name is "firefox" as opposed to "Firefox."