# Python web scraping on site that requires login every time

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, request, response

I've tried a few different methods for this, detailed here
[How to scrape a website that requires login first with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039643/how-to-scrape-a-website-that-requires-login-first-with-python)
https://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/

The problem I've realized is that the website I am attempting to scrape requires a login every time (there's no "keep me logged in" check box) so when I make the request (with cookies passed in) I still get

```
response=requests.get("URL behind login", headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to paste an error of some sort? Sadly the answer here may be very dependent on the login mechanism the site uses, etc, but a quick search in SO pointed me to another potential route for you given you are using `requests`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737740/python-requests-and-persistent-sessions

Answer (score 0):

```
cookiesObject = await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies')
print(cookiesObject)
with open('cookiesfile.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
     json.dump(cookiesObject, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
with open('cookiesfile.json') as data_file:
    data_loaded = json.load(data_file)
for cookie in data_loaded:
    await page.setCookie(cookie)
await page.goto('url')
```

**Go by this method for saving current browsing session for next use**

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.